# Why my neural network model is not able to learn a simple linear function?

Tags: neural-network, dataset, data, linear-regression, overfitting

I'm trying, using a neural network, to predict a simple relation $ f(x) = 1-x $.
I write my function this way: $f(x) = 1 - x^{+} + (-x)^{+} $ or in a more data-scientistic way: $f(x)= 1-Relu(x)+Relu(-x)$.Thus, I have an idea about the optimal weights my model should find and an appropriate architecture for the latter.
So I choosed this architecture:

```
X = np.random.uniform(-5., 5., size=(50000, 1))
y = 1-X
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='relu', input_shape=(1, )))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd')
model.fit(X, y, epochs=200, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10)])
```

My model is struggling to predict this relation and is, by far, outperformed by a 'simple' linear regression ( got a rmse of $10^{-13}$ versus a rmse of $10^{-31}$ for linear regression )
I am wondering why my model can't reach the optimal weights. I tried to increase the number of epochs and use a validation set to avoid overfitting but the optimal weights are not reached.
Can someone please advise me how to get rid of this problem and make my Neural Network predicts this linear relation?
Thanks

Comment: If your model is already able to achieve a loss in the order of $10^{-13}$ then difference with the linear regression model is really small and doesn't necessarily indicate a problem with your network. It might simply be that at that point the learning rate is too high for the model to reach a lower loss.

Comment: I'd suggest you to have a look at the weight matrix and the bias vectors given that you have such a small net and you know how the weights should look like

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll change the learning rate and see if there is any improvement